# Using conda environments after copying entire home dir

Tags: python, linux, conda, miniconda, chown

I had miniconda3 installed in `~/miniconda`. I had to reinstall my OS, so I had the entire home directory backed up. After that, I copied (most) dirs back into the newly created home dir. As well as `.bashrc` (which contains a few lines that make sure conda ends up on the $PATH). Pretty much everything else is the same (same distro, python still installed, the same username).

When trying to run any `conda` command, I get the error `bash: /home/andrei/miniconda3/bin/conda: Permission denied`. I tried running `sudo chown -R andrei:andrei miniconda3` in `~`, but I still get the same error when trying to run any `conda` command.

How would I fix this?

I would prefer to just access the environments I have, as some of the packages were actually compiled/took a very long time to download.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the solution was `sudo chmod -R 777 miniconda3`. Not sure why no other answer on SO mentioned it.